# Is the set of eigenvalues of a bounded operator on a separable Hilbert space countable?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

The spectrum of an operator is often uncountable, but please note that the question refers to *eigenvalues*.

This is well known for self-adjoint operators, but I don't see how the result extends beyond that case.

The same question also makes sense for separable Banach spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same question is asked and answered on mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78220/countability-of-eigenvalues-of-a-linear-operator). The backwards shift operator $T : \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ defined by $$T(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots) = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$$ does the job. For every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda|<1$, the geometric sequence $v = (1,\lambda,\lambda^2,\ldots)$ is square-integrable and satisfies $T v = \lambda v$.

Comment: Brilliant!  Also a bit embarassing since I have seen this example a long time ago!

Comment: Thanks also as this allowed me to answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3792095/countability-of-the-set-of-t-such-that-e-tb-is-not-injective/3792204#3792204

Comment: @Ruy: nice work! :)